# Combinatorial proof $\sum_{k=0}^n {{n}\choose{k}}^2 \ m^k = \sum_{j=0}^n {{n}\choose{j}} \ {{2n - j}\choose{n}} \ (m-1)^j$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

Combinatorial proof ($n > 0, m > 1$):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {{n}\choose{k}}^2 \ m^k = \sum_{j=0}^n {{n}\choose{j}} \ {{2n - j}\choose{n}} \ (m-1)^j$$

I came up with a story that work only for one side of the equation and doesn't for the another.

Starting from the LHS:

W are enumerating ordered trios of elements $(k, L_1, L_2)$ where $k$ is an integer $\in [0,n]$ and $L_1$ is a group of $k$ elements $\in [0,n]$ and $L_2$ is a group of $k$ elements $\in [0,n]$ each holding a value $\in [1,m]$. In that scenario, the choices of elements making $L_1$ and $L_2$ are independent of each other.

That type of thinking doesn't seem to work for the RHS. There I am choosing from $2n-j$ and that looks like a set of combined $2$ sets of $n$ elements without $j$ elements that I have chosen previously. That seems to indicate that both choises should be dependent on each other.

Also I have no idea why on the RHS there would be $(m-1)^j$ if on the LHS I have $m^k$. All things aside, those should be the same since we are talking about the choice of values from set $m$ which is not dependent on anything in a summation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a partial answer: handling the powers algebraically and the coefficients by a combinatorial proof.

**Lemma**: for $0\le j\le n$ we have
$$\sum_{k=j}^n \binom nk^2\binom kj=\binom nj\binom{2n-j}n\ .$$

**Proof**.  Choose a set $A$ of size $j$ from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and a set $B$ of size $n$, disjoint from $A$, from $\{1,\ldots,2n\}-A$.  Doing it the obvious way gives the right-hand side.  Alternatively, choose $B$ by picking $k$ elements from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ which will *not* be in $B$, and $k$ from $\{n+1,\ldots,2n\}$ which will.  Then from the former choose $j$ elements for $A$.  This requires $j\le k\le n$ and gives the left-hand side.

Then for the algebra: to simplify notation I write $m+1$ instead of your $m$.  Then
$$\eqalign{
  \sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk^2(m+1)^k
  &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk^2\sum_{j=0}^k \binom kj m^j\cr
  &=\sum_{j=0}^n\Bigl(\sum_{k=j}^n \binom nk^2\binom kj\Bigr)m^j\cr
  &=\sum_{j=0}^n \binom nj\binom{2n-j}n m^j\ .\cr}$$

Comment: how it's possible that: $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk^2\sum_{j=0}^k \binom kj m^j =\sum_{j=0}^n\Bigl(\sum_{k=j}^n \binom nk^2\binom kj\Bigr)m^j$?

Comment: on the LHS, for a fixed $k$ we have products of ${{n}\choose{k}}^2$ and of sum of ${{k}\choose{j}} m^j$ for $j \in [k,n] $. On the RHS we have products of sum of ${{n}\choose{k}}^2 {{k}\choose{j}}$ and $m^j$. So this time ${{n}\choose{k}}^2$ is diffferent in every part of that sum.

Comment: in the algebraic part, the first equation comes from binomial theorem, but I don't understand the second one @David

Comment: Changing order of summation: if we have terms $a_{j,k}$ then$$\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^k a_{j,k}=\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=j}^n a_{j,k}$$because both sides are the sum of all $a_{j,k}$ with $0\le j\le k\le n$.